# Ubuntu mouse stopped working

Tags: unity, mouse, 15.04

I'm on Ubuntu 15.04 and I'm experiencing a very strange problem with the mouse pointer. It moves without any problem but it doesn't click, it doesn't right click, the page forward and page backwards buttons on it don't work, it seems that only the movement is being registered. And when I hover over a clickable thing such as a link or a button the icon doesn't change to the little hand icon. Also the mouse refuses to switch between monitors. And a bit more of an unrelated problem. I'm using a Corsair k70 RGB keyboard and the media keys won't work in ubuntu. But after this problem happens they work totally fine. This problem has happened to me once or twice a week to me for quite a while now and today it struck the last nerve.The problem usually gets fixed when I do a restart.

Comment: You say that it doesn't right click, but does it left click? Also, are you using a track-pad on a laptop or an actual mouse connected to a desktop PC?

Comment: The only thing that works is the mouse movement, nothing else. It is an actual mouse and it is connected to my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was just narrowing down solutions here, because there are some known solutions for trackpads with similar "non-clicking" issues. Have you tried clicking on "System Settings", then "Software & Updates", then clicking on the "Additional Drivers" tab? Wait for it to search the available drivers, and enable any keyboard/mouse driver that needs to be installed. See if that works.

Comment: There were no keyboard/mouse drivers. Also I am on a laptop, but I'm using a mouse. It has never occurred to me to try to use the track-pad during the bug. The problem has not happened since I posted the question so when it does happen I'll give feedback, assuming it isn't solved by then of course.

Comment: Well, that's good to hear. Keep us updated, there might be some additional things we can try. :)

Comment: @juanjalvarez did it happen again and/or did you manage to fix it? I think I'm having the same problem on a thinkpad laptop. For me it seems (from second hand, it is not my laptop) that also the touchpad doesn't work. Tracpad I've yet to verify.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it also affected my wireless network - couldn't use mouse or connect to wifi. All devices were found, but I was getting a bunch of errors.

Turned out that I reset BIOS to factory defaults (then updated them to what I thought I needed) and this was my problem. I had to go back into the BIOS and find a little setting called "IOMMU". Enabling this solved all my issues.

I found this out by looking in dmesg and finding a little nugget that said something like "couldn't find MMU... disabling. blah blah...". Once it was enabled, the irq remapping gets enabled and (i guess) the IRQs don't bash anymore.

Anyways - hope this helps others in a similar situation.